# Cannot set property of innerHTML of null

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a form filler chrome extension. But keep getting the error cannot set property of innerHTML of null. I am trying to fill in text boxes.

I understand that I am getting the error because innerHTML requires a value for document.getElementById(""), but the value I am trying to get is from the web page. So is there some way I can go about that.

manifest-

```
{
"name": "Jabord",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Fill forms",
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches" : ["https://boards.greenhouse.io/*"],
    "js" : ["popup.js"]
}],
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon" : "download.png"
}
}
```

popup.html-

```
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" id="fill">Fill</button><br>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

popup.js-

```
document.getElementById("fill").onclick = Fill;

function Fill(){
document.getElementById("first_name").innerHTML = 
"somefirstname";
}
```

Comment: What does the html section of the page you're trying to inject the text into look like?  From the looks of it, there isn't an element where `id="first_name"`.  `getElementById` returns null when it can't find a node, and `innerHtml` isn't accessible.

Comment: It’s a job application page, and I am trying to fill in fields like first name

Comment: The id for first name is “first_name”